# Shell - Taking the input from the user from each line

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to take the input from the user into an array but Shell is accepting user input separated by spaced. Is there any way to accept the user input given separately in each line. My code below:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "enter the servers names..."
read -a array
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
echo $i
done
exit 0
```

Input:

```
hello world
```

I want to the input to be taken as below (in two different lines):

```
hello
world
```

Kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: Set `IFS=$'\n'` before your `read` to only break on newlines. (you can save the old value, e.g. (`oldIFS=IFS` before changing it, the restore the original `IFS=oldIFS` after the loop -- not necessary here because you just `exit`)

Comment: you mean this way  - `IFS=$'\n' read -a array`  ?

Comment: It sounds like you want to preprocess the input.  Try `tr -s ' ' '\n' | read -a ...`, and be aware that this will make it so the variables are only available within the subshell created by the pipe.  This will also take care of blank lines for you (unless that blank line is at the start of the input).

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the delimiter of `read` to stop reading, rather than newline. ([read man page](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/readh.html))

> -d delim  continue until the first character of DELIM is read, rather
>               than newline

For example:
`read -d':' -a array`

If you want there is no delimiter to input, you can use a loop to read into the elements of the array, then check whether the input is null string or not.

```
i=0
read "array[$i]"
while [ "${array[$i]}" ];
do
    let "i = i+1"
    read "array[$i]"
done
```

So the input will be

```
hello
world
# > there is one more empty line
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have any delimiters in my input. They are just one word and should be given in each line

Comment: this code is perfectly working fine. But that empty line is troubling as it is taking an input

Comment: So far, i don't know how to deal with the one more empty line... Or you can input an `EOF`(ctrl-d).

Answer (score 1):

According to help read:

> Reads a single line from the standard input, or from file descriptor FD...

This loop would do instead:

```
echo "enter the servers names..."
i=0
until false; do
  read server
  [ -z "$server" ] && break
  let i=i+1
  array[$i]="$server"
done

for i in "${array[@]}"; do
  echo $i
done
exit 0
```

The loop will exit on an empty line or EOF (ctrl-D).

Example session terminated by empty line:

> @server:/tmp$ ./test.sh
>   enter the servers names...
>   se1
>   se2
>   se3
>
> se1
>   se2
>   se3

Example session terminated by EOF on the empty line after se2:

> @server:/tmp$ ./test.sh
>   enter the servers names...
>   se1
>   se2
>   se1
>   se2

Please note that I check for an empty string *while reading* the names; but it is possible to check for empty strings (or whatever else) in any loop, for example while printing them or doing other computations.

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "enter the servers names..."
read -a array -d '\n'
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
echo $i
done
exit 0
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "enter the servers names..."
readarray array
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
echo $i
done
exit 0
```